# There are no items in GNOME main menu after openSuse 11.4 upgrade

Tags: gnome, opensuse, desktop-environment

I've upgraded my openSuse os from 11.3 to 11.4. Everything went smoothly but now I cannot see any item in main menu (analog of Start in Windows) and I cannot set any background picture, so now I see a single color desktop. KDE desktop is working properly.

Machine specs:
Laptop
AMD Turion TL-56
Video Card Nvidia Go 7200 (driver from NVidia is installed)

I think there are some settings which are now preventing GNOME to initialize properly still cannot find any that could change the behavior.

Comment: Have you tried adding the menu yourself (Right Click on panel --> **Add to Panel** --> **Main Menu?**)?

Comment: Yep but it doesn't work and I cannot set the wallpaper and overall the interface is somehow clunky.

Answer (score 1):

Worse case, try removing your existing gnome configuration and see if it fixes it.  Preferably do this from a shell when not logged into Gnome:

```
mkdir gnome-backup
mv .gnome2 gnome-backup
mv .gnome2_private gnome-backup
```

And log back in to Gnome.  If this fixes it, you can either accept it or restore your configuration and dig deeper for a solution.

```
rm -rf .gnome2 .gnome2_private
cp -a gnome-backup/.gnome2 gnome-backup/.gnome2_private .
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: Another detail. I think a monitor is not configured properly because I cannot set frequency.